# Is introvert a derogatory term, or just neutral?

Tags: word-usage

Is *introvert* a derogatory term? Does it have the potential to offend someone, or is it okay to call someone who enjoys solitude an introvert?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Introvert and extrovert are terms used in psychology and study of personality types. It's not derogatory, though our society tends to value extroversion over introversion. Silly us.

Comment: Lots of terms used in psychology can be offensive. Just because it has a scientific meaning doesn't mean people won't take offence.

Answer (score 4):

A long-winded discussion on introversion and extraversion is way beyond the scope of this website; however, generally speaking, introverted people tend to avoid big crowds and enjoy solitary activities.

The word in itself has no explicit negative connotation associated with it, as it's simply considered a type of personality by professionals like psychologists. That being said, however, in especially Western societies, introversion is often stigmatized and stereotyped by others, such as in the media and is generally (incorrectly) considered undesirable.

Comment: I would argue that it is stereotyped in this way because what seems like a fun time can seem like torture to the opposite group. Extroverts might see an Introvert at a party and think they are not having fun and being a "party-downer", even though the introvert is having a great time. And since 1)Extroverts tend to express their opinions more loudly, and 2) group events tend to cater to extroverts, it is their opinions that tend to be heard more often.

Answer (score 3):

There is a potential for offense, depending on how the comment is taken. However, this is more to do with perception than the actual term. I would happily describe myself as an introvert, because it is true - most of the time.

It can be taken with the sense of "loner, sad jonny-no-friends", as if you are implying that they are the sort of person who no-one would want to know. It seems most likely to be taken like that by people for whom this is partly true.

So take some care over how it is used. But, for the majority of people, it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think other people defining you as introvert can be taken as an insult especially if they don't know you that well.  You can be relatively shy, but love big crowds and sometimes you can be quiet with some people and a lunatic with others and that can be quiet normal to depend on your level of comfort. So there should also be a comfortovert.

Comment: What's a "comfortovert"? Aside from that, welcome to EL&U. Enjoy our [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.